# Customize drop shadow in Plasma 5.3

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

How can I customize drop shadow of the windows in Plasma 5.3_

I would like to have a stronger/bigger shadow like in MacOS

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you are referring to?

Comment: I have edited my original post...

Answer (score 2):

**Plasma shadows**

The Plasma 4/5 shadows are set in the plasma theme. From the KDE TechBase  - https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Theme :

> A feature of Plasma is the ability to theme desktop elements using
>   Scalable Vector Graphics (SVGs)...

[image]

Plasma 4 theme details: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma4/ThemeDetails

Plasma 5 theme details: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma5/ThemeDetails

Same kind of: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?68242-Drop-shadows

Comment: So, this means the only way to customize it is to create a new theme?

Comment: or edit an existing theme.